# Java SecurityManager context aware framework

Tags: java, security

Most security managers are pretty much static and implement a fixed set of rules for the entire system. They rarely change depending on what code is attempting some operation.

I am after a security manager framework that is dynamic, where different sub systems have different "security managers" applying different restrictions. Each thread is naturally independent and unaffected by others. It goes without saying that creating new threads assigns a minimal or default set of restrictions.

The framework should handle all the boring tracking work probably using a stack to push and pop the persmissions currently in use for a particular thread.

A code path that invokes three separate sub systems would do the right thing and apply the rules for each and each only. When the system invokes the next it would update the current context and continue. The proxying layer at the boundaries should be part of the f/w.

A > B > C

I know i can attempt to right this myself i was just hoping that someone was aware of a foss library that had already solved the tricky bits so i can leverage their hard work. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Threads are unfortunately not naturally independent in Java. Applets/WebStart use ThreadGroups (and stack inspection) to separate contexts.